# How to remove square brackets from list in Python?

Tags: python, list, output

```
LIST = ['Python','problem','whatever']
print(LIST)
```

When I run this program I get

```
[Python, problem, whatever]
```

Is it possible to remove that square brackets from output?

Comment: I suggest `map` instead of `str(i) for i in LIST` - `map` is C code so it's faster

Comment: list comprehension is actually faster than map in Python2 because it does not create a stack frame that is computationally expensive. map creates it.  But this behavior is problematic that the variable in the list comprehension could leak due to rebinding if a variable with the same name was declared before.  The list comprehension in Python3 does not exhibit such problem because it's changed to create a stack frame to be consistent with generator expressions.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could convert it to a string instead of printing the list directly:

```
print(", ".join(LIST))
```

If the elements in the list aren't strings, you can convert them to string using either `repr` (if you want quotes around strings) or `str` (if you don't), like so:

```
LIST = [1, "foo", 3.5, { "hello": "bye" }]
print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in LIST ) )
```

Which gives the output:

```
1, 'foo', 3.5, {'hello': 'bye'}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have numbers in my LIST?

Comment: @GregorGajič then ", ".join(str(i) for i in LIST)

Comment: How can i remove the first bracket if like this, `[['String-1','String-2','String-3']]` and the result will be like this `['String-1','String-2','String-3']`

Comment: Nedy Supriantino , just slice the list like so: `list[0]`

Answer (score 45):

Yes, there are several ways to do it. For instance, you can convert the list to a string and then remove the first and last characters:

```
l = ['a', 2, 'c']
print str(l)[1:-1]
'a', 2, 'c'
```

If your list contains only strings and you want remove the quotes too then you can use the `join` method as has already been said.

Answer (score 23):

if you have numbers in list, you can use `map` to apply `str` to each element:

```
print ', '.join(map(str, LIST))
```

^ `map` is C code so it's faster than `str(i) for i in LIST`

Answer (score 16):

```
def listToStringWithoutBrackets(list1):
    return str(list1).replace('[','').replace(']','')
```