# How to perfectly convert one-element list to tuple in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, python-3.5

So I am trying to do this:

```
tuple([1])
```

The output I expect is :

```
(1)
```

However, I got this:

```
(1,)
```

But if I do this:

```
tuple([1,2])
```

It works perfectly! like this:

```
(1,2)
```

This is so weird that I don't know why the tuple function cause this result.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: The type for `(1)`  is integer; while `(1,)` is tuple.

Comment: So (1,) just looks not perfectly. But in fact it is a tuple only contains one element?

Comment: Maybe you are not looking for a tuple, better something like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207713/5393621

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is such a common question that the [Python Wiki has a page dedicated to it](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax):

> **One Element Tuples**
>
> One-element tuples look like:
>
> `1,`
>
> The essential element here is the trailing comma. As for any
>   expression, parentheses are optional, so you may also write
>   one-element tuples like
>
> `(1,)`
>
> but it is the comma, not the parentheses, that define the tuple.

Comment: So (1,) just looks not perfectly. But in fact it is a tuple only contains one element?

Comment: @MarsLee Actually, `1,` is a tuple that only contains one element. `(1,)` is just a pretty version of the same :) Try it yourself: `for i in 1,2,3,: print i` - the tuple is `1,2,3,`, putting parenthesis around it just makes it easy for the lexer to realise it's a tuple and not confuse it with something else.

Comment: I totally got it. Really appreciate for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

use

```py
.format(str(tuple(mwo)).replace(",)",")")))
```

This will replace comma from the first element.

Comment: if you just want to use it in SQL with  IN operator                                                                   
`list = ",".join(str(x) for x in [1,2])
list = f"({list})"`

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to convert it to your expected representation (i.e. `(1)`), which as mentioned by others isn't a tuple for the singular case, you can use this approach - which will generate a string formatted output as the singular  case isn't a valid tuple:

```
f"({str(your_list)[1:-1]})"
```

E.g

```
>>> f"({str([1])[1:-1]})"
'(1)'
>>> f"({str([1,2])[1:-1]})"
'(1,2)'
```

Answer (score 2):

That is how tuples are formed in python. Using just `(1)` evaluates to 1, just as much as using `(((((((1)))))))` evaluates to `((((((1))))))` to `(((((1)))))` to... 1.

Using `(1,)` explicitly tells python you want a tuple of one element

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting is a tuple. When there is only a single element, then it has to be represented with a comma, to show it is a tuple.

Eg)

```
>>> a = (1)
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = (1,)
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

The reason is, when you do not use a comma when there is only one element, the interpreter evaluates it like an expression grouped by paranthesis, thus assigning `a` with a value of the type returned by the expression

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms)

> ### 6.2.3. Parenthesized forms
>
> A parenthesized form is an optional expression list enclosed in parentheses:
>
> ```
> parenth_form ::=  "(" [expression_list] ")"
> ```
>
> A parenthesized expression
>   list yields whatever that expression list yields: if the list contains
>   at least one comma, it yields a tuple; otherwise, it yields the single
>   expression that makes up the expression list.
>
> An empty pair of parentheses yields an empty tuple object. Since
>   tuples are immutable, the rules for literals apply (i.e., two
>   occurrences of the empty tuple may or may not yield the same object).
>
> Note that tuples are not formed by the parentheses, but rather by use
>   of the comma operator. The exception is the empty tuple, for which
>   parentheses are required — allowing unparenthesized “nothing” in
>   expressions would cause ambiguities and allow common typos to pass
>   uncaught.

So `(1,)` really is a tuple

Answer (score 0):

`(1)` is just `1` in grouping parentheses - it's an integer. `(1,)` is the 1-element tuple you want.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior in Python. You get a Tuple with one element. The notation (1,) is just a reminder that you got such a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The output (1,) is fine. The , is to mark a single element tuple.

If

```
a = (1)
```

a is really a integer

If

```
a = (1, )
```

Then a is a tuple.