# Pandas. read html write to csv

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

Old code reads HTML and output it to CSV

I have an old python 3 code:

```
self.df, = pandas.read_html(my_html_file)
self.df.to_csv(my_csv_file, index=False)
```

without comma in first line pandas returns a list, with the comma DF object that can be send to CSV file in second line.
I do not understand that comma in the first line

Comment: Please make the question more clear! Maybe try giving an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it convert one element `list` to scalar by [one element tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36637630), because [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) return `list of DataFrames` - in your code `one DataFrame list`.

**Sample**:

```
a = [1]
b, = a
#() are optional
#(b,) = a
print (b)
1
```

More readable is select first list by indexing - `[0]`:

```
self.df = pandas.read_html(my_html_file)[0]
self.df.to_csv(my_csv_file, index=False)
```