# Export list of values into csv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am using Python 2.x on Win7.

My question is:

I got a list of numbers: `angle = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
and I would like to export the numbers to a csv file. So the csv should look like:

```
0 | 1 | 2 |...| 10 |
```

But so far what I got in csv file is:

```
[0 | 1 | 2 |...| 10] |
```

My code is:

```
angle = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
ldsvp = open("C:\Controlled NP\\" + "LDS1.csv", 'ab')
with open('LDS1.csv', 'wb') as output:
   ldsvp.write('Angle' + ',' + str(angle))
   ldsvp.write('\n')
```

So...any advice to remove the `[` and `]` from the csv file?

Comment: `','.join([str(a) for a in angle])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove square brackets from list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207697/how-to-remove-square-brackets-from-list-in-python)

Comment: @Julien In these cases, I prefer the succinctness of `','.join(map(str, angle))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Comment: So, just to be clear, when you do `str(my_list)`, it creates a string representation of the *list*, which will look a lot like the list literal you would write in source code. If you are actually writing a csv file, I suggest using the `csv` modules.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga python has csv module which makes the job easier.

An example would be

```
import csv
import os

def csvWriter(file):
    if os.path.exists(file):
        mode = "ab"
    else:
        mode = "wb"

    with open(file, mode) as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow([rec for rec in range(1, 11)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csvWriter('names.csv')
```

The output looks like this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```